# SpringBootTest - how to assert if context loading fails

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, listener, spring-boot-test

I wrote an *ApplicationListener* that should check if the environment is prepared during context initialization. I'm having trouble testing the scenario since I'm adding the listener manually both in my *configure()* and *main()* methods.

ApplicationListener class:

```
public class EnvironmentPrepared implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {

        @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
            //code that checks if conditions are met

            if (checkTrue) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
    public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);
        return application.listeners(new EnvironmentPrepared()).sources(MyApp.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class);
        springApplication.addListeners(new EnvironmentPrepared());
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
}
```

The test I want to execute:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = OverriddenProfilesTest.CustomLoader.class)
public class OverriddenProfilesTest {

    public static class CustomLoader extends SpringBootContextLoader {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplication getSpringApplication() {
            SpringApplication app = super.getSpringApplication();
            app.addListeners(new EnvironmentPrepared());
            return app;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if spring can bootstrap everything 
     */
    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

This would be the test I want. A *RuntimeException* is thrown but the exception happens during context initialization so the test doesn't even start.

Comment: you can try to load it programmatically inside your test method, check the hierarchy of `AbstractApplicationContext`, for xml configuration for example something like: `ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("my-app-context.xml");`

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have tried it with the AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext but it didn't work how I expected. Seems to me that generally creating another context creates more problems. You can check out the solution I used beneath...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I used. I removed the manual adding of the listener to the application and used spring.factories file instead.

Regarding the test, I first created a custom runner class:

```
    public class SpringRunnerWithExpectedExceptionRule extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner {

public SpringRunnerWithExpectedExceptionRule(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
    super(clazz);
}

@Override
protected Statement methodBlock(FrameworkMethod frameworkMethod) {
    List<ExpectedException> testRules = getTestClass().getAnnotatedFieldValues(null, ExpectedExceptionClassRule.class, ExpectedException.class);
    Statement result = super.methodBlock(frameworkMethod);
    for (TestRule item : testRules) {
        result = item.apply(result, getDescription());
    }
    return result;
}}
```

Then I create following annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD })
public @interface ExpectedExceptionClassRule {

}
```

And finally, I was able to run the test with my runner:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunnerWithExpectedExceptionRule.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class OverriddenProfilesTest {

    @ExpectedExceptionClassRule
    public static ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void before() {
        expectedException.expectCause(runtimeExceptionMethod());
    }


    @Test
    public void testThatShouldThrowExceptionWhileSettingContext {
    }

    static Matcher<Throwable> runtimeExceptionMethod() {
        return new IsRuntimeException();
    }

    static class IsRuntimeException extends TypeSafeMatcher<Throwable> {
    //do stuff
    }
```

More on the solution can be found [here](https://github.com/helospark/spring-context-init-fail-test).